# Pagination with php PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I've got a problem with pagination with PDO in php
here's my code:

```
//pagination
        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = intval($this->request->get['page']);
        }
        else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $itemsPerPage = 30;

        $start = $itemsPerPage * ($page - 1);

        //Dims92 products
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM oc_crawled_products WHERE store = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(["dims92", $start, $itemsPerPage]);
        $this->data['dimsProducts'] = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have runned the query `SELECT * FROM  oc_crawled_products WHERE store = "dims92" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30` and it's working fine. But when I try it with the php pdo code it returns an `array` with size of `0` and I can't find the mistake.

Comment: what is this `$query->execute(["dims92", $start, $itemsPerPage]);`

Comment: @Akintunde : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php ... assuming `$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);` was successful.

Comment: as far as I know it replaces the `?` signs with the values. The first `?` will be replaces with `"dims92"`, the second `?` with `0` and so on.

Comment: try $query->execute(array("dims92", $start, $itemsPerPage));

Comment: @Jens I've tried it. It's still not working.

Comment: You have to bind them with `bindParam()`, as they needs to be represented integers, not strings. Or, you can disable prepared emultaes.